# First() INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

```
SELECT tblT.Tick, First(tblB.BDF) AS FirstOfBDF
FROM tblT INNER JOIN tblB ON tblT.Tick = tblB.Tick
GROUP BY tblT.Tick;
```

My Access table (tblB) is sorted by Tick and then by BDF. How come it does not retrieve the correct data?

Comment: why you use _first()_

Comment: In SQL, tables *aren't* sorted. There may be some specific guarantees given by your database product, but for the general language, your statement isn't true. Please add which database system you're using as a tag.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : The _FIRST() function_ is only supported in MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee that table is sorted unless you explicitly mention `Order by`.

```
select top 1  tblT.Tick, First(tblB.BDF) AS FirstOfBDF
 from FROM tblT INNER JOIN tblB ON tblT.Tick = tblB.Tick
    GROUP BY tblT.Tick
    Order by tblt.Tick ;
```